# Averaging values in a table by recognizing the name of the column header

Tags: r

I have the following table called m:

```
Identifier  DAT_SN_e15.5_1  DAT_SN_e15.5_2  DAT_SN_p2_1 DAT_SN_p2_2
100009600   3           1           0           0
100009609   13          4           1           6
100009614   0           0           0           0
100009664   9           17          5           7
100012          0           0           0           0
100017          0           0           0           0
100019          1275            70          54          353
100033459   0           0           0           0
100034251   0           0           0           0
100034361   277         4           114         830
```

Column number 1 is the gene identifier, column 2 and 3 are biological replicates of DAT_SN_e15.5, column 4 and 5 are biological replicates of DAT_SN_p2. My real world data consists of 56 such samples each having 2 replicates. Is there a way to recognize replicates based on their name and the only difference being the 1 or 2 at the end of the name?

If so how could I create a new table m.rep<- that averages the 2 values for each identifier and each sample and contains the gene identifier, the columns named DAT_SN_e15.5_ave and DAT_SN_p2_ave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to use fuzzy search or for approximate matches to pattern using `agrep`.

```
## you replace nn by your colnames
nn <- c('DAT_SN_e15.5_1','DAT_SN_e15.5_2','DAT_SN_p2_1','DAT_SN_p2_2')
## for each column name find which column is approximately similar
ll <- lapply(seq_along(nn),function(x)
          nn[agrep(nn[x],nn)]) 
## remove duplicate since a is similar to n and b is similar to a
ll[!duplicated(ll)]

[[1]]
[1] "DAT_SN_e15.5_1" "DAT_SN_e15.5_2"

[[2]]
[1] "DAT_SN_p2_1" "DAT_SN_p2_2"
```

**edit** here how you can use the above, using your data

```
dat <- read.table(text='Identifier  DAT_SN_e15.5_1  DAT_SN_e15.5_2  DAT_SN_p2_1 DAT_SN_p2_2
100009600   3           1           0           0
100009609   13          4           1           6
100009614   0           0           0           0
100009664   9           17          5           7
100012          0           0           0           0
100017          0           0           0           0
100019          1275            70          54          353
100033459   0           0           0           0
100034251   0           0           0           0
100034361   277         4           114         830',header=TRUE)

nn <- colnames(dat)[-1]

ll <- lapply(seq_along(nn),function(x)
  nn[agrep(nn[x],nn)])
ll <- ll[!duplicated(ll)]

res <- lapply(ll,function(x)rowMeans(dat[,x]))
res <- t(do.call(rbind,res))
## i take the first element of the pair as a column name
colnames(res) <- lapply(ll,'[[',1)


     DAT_SN_e15.5_1 DAT_SN_p2_1
 [1,]            2.0         0.0
 [2,]            8.5         3.5
 [3,]            0.0         0.0
 [4,]           13.0         6.0
 [5,]            0.0         0.0
 [6,]            0.0         0.0
 [7,]          672.5       203.5
 [8,]            0.0         0.0
 [9,]            0.0         0.0
[10,]          140.5       472.0
```

Comment: agstudy, thanks a lot for trying to help me! I have to admit though after reading your post many times that I just don't understand it. Is there an averaging of the samples in that and is the output a new table? Sorry but I am fairly new to this just starting to get a grasp on things.

Comment: @Exist_HUPD here i am giving you how you can group biolgical replicates. You can use my result to do the average part.

Comment: It definitely works flawlessly in finding the replicates and averaging them correctly, so I that is a big step forward for me and I appreciate your help! Unfortunately I am not able to take the resulting list and turn it back into a table. I searched and tried several solutions including as.data(as.matrix) as well as the melt function but I remain unsuccessful. It would be fantastic if you could explain how I can turn this back into a table. Thanks

Comment: @Exist_HUPD I add another step to transform the resulted list into data.frame.

Comment: You are a RockstaR thanks! and I kind of starting to understand it.